# React Bootstrap component doesn't appear when I load it in my App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a react component called ImagePost and when I call it in my App.js it doesn't appear.

```js
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';

const ImagePost = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Container fluid>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={6} md={4}>
            <Image className='fluid' src={require('../Images/lonepeak.jpg')} responsive/>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ImagePost
```

[Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4UIV.png)

Comment: Not enough information. Please show the code of `App.js` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your relative path for the image source to:

```
src={require("./../Images/lonepeak.jpg")}
```

Alternatively import your image same as you would any other resource/package:

```
import lonepeak from "./../Images/lonepeak.jpg";
```

and use it like this:

```
src={lonepeak}
```